# How to connect neptune and nodejs without nat gateway

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-neptune

I want to create neptune without nat gateway and connect with nodejs. Can explain step by steps this cienario.

Comment: Are you planning to run the node.js code in a Lambda funciton?  If your node.js code is going to run in a Lambda function, then all you need to do is make sure you Lambda function is configured to run in the same VPC as where Neptune is located.